# Ошибка в построении предложения с однородными членами

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, однородные-члены

> Фильмы Эльдара Рязанова отличает удивительный юмор, не только вызывающий смех, но и грусть.

В чем здесь ошибка? Не могу найти однородные члены, которые неправильно употреблены.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Корректно: Фильмы Эльдара Рязанова отличает удивительный юмор,  вызывающий **не только смех, но и грусть.**

Однородные члены **смех, грусть** объединены двойным союзом **«НЕ ТОЛЬКО ... НО И».** Однако первая часть двойного союза находится не на своем месте. Нужно поставить ее перед «смех».

Answer (score 0):

**юмор**
1. Добродушный смех, незлобивая насмешка. // Отношение к чему-либо, проникнутое таким настроением.
2. Приём в произведениях литературы и искусства, основанный на изображении чего-либо в комическом, смешном виде. // Совокупность художественных произведений, проникнутых таким отношением к действительности.
[**Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка**](http://vslovare.ru/slovo/tolkovjyij-slovar-efremovoij/jumor-m/522444)

*Думаю*, что в предложении есть ещё одна неточность [*@Серж* уже объяснил особенности союза "не только... но и"]:
юмор (по определению) и есть особый вид смеха (юмористический, юморной = смешной; юмореска = смешная история).

Поэтому, *мне кажется*, предложение может иметь такой вид:
*Фильмы Эльдара Рязанова отличает удивительный юмор, вызывающий не только **улыбку**, но и грусть.*

Comment: См. п. 2. Прием, основанный на изображении чего-либо в комическом, смешном виде. Чаплин, Рязанов, Жванецкий и им подобные (в хорошем смысле слова), используя этот прием, вызывают не только смех, но и грусть, потому что их юмор как бы многосторонний, вы смеетесь и грустите одновременно, например, жалеeте этого смешного героя. – М_Г 16 часов назад